# VS Web Essentials 2012 compile master LESS on imported save

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less, web-essentials

I am trying to maintain a global .less file which @imports the rest of the application .less files.

I am currently developing this project in Visual Studio 2012 using the Web Essentials extension which automatically generates css files on save.

However it only compiles the .less file which has just been saved and it's children and I want upstream "master" .less files which @import the current file to be compiled.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You can hit F6 or Shift+F6 to build the solution/project, which will save your changes and in conjunction with the setting Mads describes, cascade them to the master LESS file.  My short cut had been overridden so you may need to set one up with Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard and filter for Build.BuildSolution/Selection

Answer (score 5):

In the latest nightly build, you now have an option to compile all LESS files on build. That takes care of the import chain issue when updating chained LESS files. Get the latest nightly here: http://madskristensen.net/custom/webessentials2012.vsix?1.8.9.1

Comment: thanks for the info. I appreciate the work you're doing on this. I'm trying to get a good workflow going to not slow down development so apologies if I sound demanding! If the project needs to build every time I save a file this seems a little excessive to me.

Comment: Also, am I able to trigger a build on a file save to that matter? Thanks

Comment: I agree with Dave that it would be really useful if saving a LESS file could be cascaded to any importing files without triggering a build.

Comment: Yes getting it to build all LESS files on save in one, would be very much appreciated. having to save several files, because you have imports is a hassle and would be very cool if it happened on a save of one LESS file. It could even do it only if it imports the saved file.