# Better LESS compiler options for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, compiler-construction, less

I'm new to VS, coming from the Mac where I used the excellent CodeKit for LESS compiling.  I've installed the Web Essentials add-on, so I have basic LESS support and compiling.

The major shortcoming with this plugin is when saving files that are imported into a main.less file, the main.less file does not compile unless I open it specifically and save it.

I'd prefer a solution like CodeKit, which would compile the parent file if any of the children are modified.  Are there any other plugins, even commercial ones, which do this?

There's an option in Web Essentials to "compile all LESS files", which would almost do what I want, but it throws an error:

[image]

Comment: [This](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2b96d16a-c986-4501-8f97-8008f9db141a) may be an option...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS Web Essentials 2012 compile master LESS on imported save](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415729/vs-web-essentials-2012-compile-master-less-on-imported-save)

Answer (score 1):

In WebEssentials there is an option (<kbd>tools</kbd>><kbd>Options</kbd>><kbd>WebEssentials</kbd>><kbd>Less</kbd>) to Compile all files on Build, which you'll probably do before publishing anyway. [You might want to add your votes to the UserVoice ticket for this issue](http://webessentials.uservoice.com/forums/140520-general/suggestions/4025999-recompile-all-less-files-in-the-project-right-afte).

[BundleTransformer](https://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/) allows you to have ASP.NET do the transformations on the fly (at runtime), having it compile, minify and compress all in one go. You won't have to recompile your files inside Visual Studio itself. You can keep using WebEssentials for intellisense.

And then there is the [Mindscape Web Workbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench) which provides similar functionality as Webessentials. Their Pro edition ($) can also compile files on save & build.

Comment: Can mindscape save all less files when you save one?

Also: Alt-Shift-Y in VS2012 fails for me...

Comment: Not sure, my colleague was very pleased with it, I usually don't venture into the stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer http://wearekiss.com/simpless You can use it even in Express edition since it's not integrated inside VS.

Just open the Simpless drag and drop the file and it will compile your file automatically when they has been modified from your VS (or any of editor).

Web Essential is also have suggest in someone answer.